# Loading Image from Asp.net core Web API 3.1 Folder outside of "wwwroot"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, static-files

I'm trying to load images from a folder in Asp.net Core 3.1 Web API by entering URL in the browser. But getting 404 error.

[image]

Here are the configurations of my Startup.cs:

[image: static-file-configuration]
[image]

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: What happens when you remove "api/" from that URL?

Comment: Yup. It worked.

Comment: Please close this as you sort out issue @ArfizurRahman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after removing `api/` from the URL. Thanks to @CaptainKenpachi for his comment.